# Differences in structural target for LPS detection by LAL and MD-2/TLR4

Tags: biochemistry, immunology, structural-biology

I remember there being a significant difference in the pathogen-associated molecular patterns (PAMPs) used for detection of lipopolysaccharide (LPS) by mammalian cells and the Limulus amoebocyte lysate (LAL) assay. However, I cannot seem to find a paper that indicated what structure on the LPS lipid A moiety is used for detection.

In humans, structure-and-function relationships exist between the phosphate groups of bisphosphorylated glucosamine disaccharide backbone as well as the six fatty acyl tails and the MD-2/TLR-4 co-receptor system.

Does anyone have a paper, or a general lead, as to where I can find what area LAL uses for detection? I haven't had much luck with Google Scholar.

Comment: I guess the LRR of the TLR is responsible for LPS-PAMP identification (Lipid A). Not too sure.